# MVC ASP.NET Return response.GetResponseStream() as FileResultStream

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, stream, httpwebresponse, fileresult

I am trying to write a controller that creates and makes a HttpWebRequest to a service that returns an Image. I then want to return this image as a FileResult. How do I go about doing that.  I have tried the code below but it returns a corrupted image instead of the full image:

```
public FileResult SomeAction()
{
    var request = Make some request here

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        string contentType = response.ContentType;
        return File(response.GetResponseStream(),contentType);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Does this post help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185494/securityexception-when-calling-graphics-drawimage

Comment: I am trying to avoid using the HttpContext.Response.OutputStream directly.

Comment: saying "It does not work" is like going to a car mechanic and saying "it makes a funny noise".

Comment: It returns a corrupted image result, rather than the full image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you fail to mention how "it doesn't work", all I can tell you is that in general what you're doing should work.  However, i'm unsure of where the response stream is actually read.  Since you're placing a return inside a using, it may be that the stream is being disposed of before the stream is actually read.  Try removing the using statement, and just doing something like this:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
File(response.GetResponseStream(), response.ContentType);
```

if that doesn't work, then verify that response is actually returning a content type, and a valid stream.

EDIT:

It would seem that I was correct, the filestream gets closed before it's read if you wrap it in a using.  You don't have to worry about disposing of the stream as File will dispose of it when it's done with it.

See this other question:

[How do I dispose my filestream when implementing a file download in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084366/how-do-i-dispose-my-filestream-when-implementing-a-file-download-in-asp-net)